# Animate css is not working in both CDN and downloded file

Tags: html, css, animation

I tried to use Animate.css (https://animate.style/) to animate some text in a html file but the text is not animated.

I used 2 methods but both do not seem to work:

1. from a CDN

and

2. I downloaded directly from github from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/daneden/animate.css/master/animate.css

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css">
    <title>Animate.css</title>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> -->
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="animated infinite jello">Animate Me</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

May I know which part of my code went wrong. Appreciate your kind advice.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing underlines between the animation name and the class. look at this example:

```
<h1 class="animate__animated animate__bounce">An animated element</h1>
```

> After installing Animate.css, add the class animate__animated to an element, along with any of the animation names (don't forget the animate__ prefix!):

Comment: Thank you, Najmieh!

I tried to make it infinite however it does not seem to work
<h1 class="animate__animated infinite animate__jello">An animated element</h1>

Comment: is this the case for all the animations? have you tried any other? note that it is double underlines.

Comment: It worked. But I added "infinite" to make it a loop, the text only animated once.

<h1 class="animate__animated infinite animate__wobble">An animated element</h1>

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with the cdn. After updating the class name as shown in the example below, I was able to get it to work.

```html
<h1 class="text-uppercase animate__wobble">An animated element</h1>
```

Looks like animate__animated is the issue with the class name.